# How can I read a file packaged with an android app through a C++ library?

Tags: c#, android, c++, unity-game-engine, android-ndk

I have written a Unity application in C# that uses a C++ library built using Android NDK. I want to read some files that are packaged with the android application (in the assets folder) from this C++ library.

NDK does provide an API that allows files to be accessed. However, this API seems to require the Java AssetManager, and I'm not sure how I can access that from C#.

Is there some way I can do so? Alternatively, is there any other way I can go about reading these assets?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that APK files are just ZIP files so you can open them like you would any zip file. C# has built in utilities for reading zip files.

Comment: I would like to make it so that Unity/C# does not need to know about the files. Only the C++ library is aware of the files. Is there a way to give the library access to the file system?

Comment: That's a totally different question. You are going to have to look into permissions for that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access files in the assets folder through the C++ library via the AssetManager. You can obtain the AssetManager through the application context via JNI calls.